# How can I achieve dynamic cell height and image height with UIView in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have some difficulty in figuring out how to dynamically have each `cell` resize according to the `UIImage` and the other content inside the `UIView`.

Heres a picture to better understand:

The grey background is the `contentView` of the `cell`.

The white on top is a `UIView`.

[image]

Here is how I am downloading images:-

inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.bigImageView.file = (PFFile *)object[@"image"];
[cell.bigImageView loadInBackground:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        }];
```

Setting the height of the cell in `heightForRow` according to the size of the cell from `storyboard`

```
return 535.0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide the `estimatedRowHeight` and `rowHeight` of your tableView as

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0 // Your estimated height of the row
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

while setting up your `tableView`.

Update:

For top left image: Leading to UIView, Top, Trailing to button, Width and height
For Button: Width, height, top, trailing to Label

### For Label: Width, height, top, trailing to UIView

For Bottom Button: leading to UIView, trailing to Label, Bottom to contentView, width, height

### For Bottom Label: Trailing to UIView, Bottom to Content View, Width , Height

For ImageView: Leading to UIView, Trailing to UIView, Top to any of items above image View, bottom to "Bottom Button" or "Bottom Label". Set its width equal to content View. No Height, Set its content Hugging property to low.

Comment: This will also resize the uiimage and uiview?

Comment: Yes, But don't forget to put trailing, leading, top, bottom constraints of UIView with relative to its ContentView.

Comment: do i also make constraints for the images, lables,buttons to the ContentView?

Comment: No, The constraints for everything inside UIView should be with relative to that UIView

Comment: do i make uiimageviews hugging horizontal or vertical low

Comment: Do i put the those two lines of code in viewDidLoad?

Comment: I have `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 535;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;` and the cell is being stretched super tall. Far beyond any of the image height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113425/discussion-between-idocode-and-farhan).

Answer (score 0):

// try like thhis

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UIImage *img = // here load image
  if (img) {
      return img.size.height + // your additional static heght
  } else {
   return 350;// defaultHeght;
  }
}
```

Comment: this answer wont work if i have more than one image.

Comment: after loading each image you need to reload that respective cell

Comment: for loading image you need to wrote one method , call that method from heightforrowAtindex method , in loading sucess you need to reload that cell